# send Ethereum to smart contact with web3.js [metamask]

Tags: solidity, web3js, transactions

this function :

```
  web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:myaddress,to:toaddress, value:web3.toWei(1, "ether")}, function(err, transactionHash) {
  if (!err)
    console.log(transactionHash); 
  });
```

completely work for send ETH from **`ethereum-acount-address`** to **`ethereum-acount-address`** BUT when i set an
**smartcontract** address for `toaddress` meta mask return

```
Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code.
```

my solidity contract is

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract mysmartContract{


        function whitdrawETH() payable public {

        }

        function getContactEthBalance() constant returns(uint) {

        return this.balance;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make smart-contract acceptable for ether you need to implement [fallback function](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.23/contracts.html?highlight=fallback#fallback-function):

```
function() public payable { }
```

> Contracts that receive Ether directly (without a function call, i.e. using send or transfer) but do not define a fallback function throw an exception, sending back the Ether (this was different before Solidity v0.4.0). So if you want your contract to receive Ether, you have to implement a fallback function.

In case you want to send ether to your smart-contract `mysmartContract` with `whitdrawETH()` function you need to send methodSignature of this function to data field like this:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
   from: myaddress,
   to: toaddress,
   data: web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature('whitdrawETH()')
   value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")
}
```

Comment: `web3.eth.abi` does no longer exists with MetaMask. It seems it moved elsewhere.

Comment: @user2284570 `web3.eth.abi` functions are a part of `web3@1.x.x`: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-abi.html. Visibility of those functions relates to the version of the web3 library do you use in your Dapp. Metamask has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score -1):

This is what worked for me:

```
receive() external payable { }
```

> This is the function that is executed on plain Ether transfers (e.g. via .send() or .transfer()). If no such function exists, but a payable fallback function exists, the fallback function will be called on a plain Ether transfer. If neither a receive Ether nor a payable fallback function is present, the contract cannot receive Ether through regular transactions and throws an exception.

More information here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.2/contracts.html#receive-ether-function